# How can I show $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I saw a lot of books said the unitary group $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, can anyone show me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=\{a_{ij}\in M_n(\mathbb{C})| |a_{ij}|>1\}$. Then if $X\in U(n)$, then $X^tX=I$, then $\sum_i \bar{x_{ij}}x_{ik}=\delta_{jk}$, so that $|x_{ij}|\le 1$. Thus $X\in B$, so that $U(n)$ is a bounded set. It is the preimage of the function $U\mapsto U^tU-I$, which is a polynomial and thus continous, and thus is closed. Thus it is closed and bounded and thus compact by the Heine-Borel theorem. For the subgroup, clearly $I\in U(n)$ and if $X, Y\in U(n)$, then  $(XY)^tXY=Y^tX^tXY=I$ and $(X^{-1})^tX^{-1}=(XX^{t})^{-1}=I$ so that it is also a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually show the compactness of $U_n(\mathbb C)$ in a bigger space, namely $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$, noting that it is a closed subset (inverse image of $S^1$ under the continuous map $\det$) of a compact set (the columns of each matrix in $U_n(\mathbb C)$ has length $1$).